# How to validate a specific Div

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validate specific divs I have looked all over google and I can't find any examples for the way I am doing my validation. I have 2 divs I want to be able to click a button and validate the first div and then I want that div to hide and validate the second div. I have wrote some jquery code that hides the first div but I only want to do this to happen once that specific div is validated.

**MARKUP**

```
<div id="contentone">

<table>
<tr>
<td>game console</td>
<td><%=Html.TextBox("console", ViewData["console"] ?? "") %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>manafacturer</td>
<td><%=Html.TextBox("manaf", ViewData["manaf"] ?? "") %></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<div id="contenttwo">

<table>
<tr>
<td>description</td>
<td><%=Html.TextBox("desc", ViewData["desc"] ?? "") %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Available games</td>
<td><%=Html.TextBox("games", ViewData["games"] ?? "") %></td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>


 <button id="hide" type="button">Test1</button>


 <script>

         $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#hide").click(function(){
                 $("#contentone").hide();
             });
         }); 

 </script>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult ConsoleQues(string console, string manaf, string desc, string games)
    {
        ViewData["console"] = console;
        ViewData["manaf"] = manaf;
    ViewData["desc"] = desc;
        ViewData["games"] = games;




        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(console))
            ModelState.AddModelError("console", "Please enter console name ");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(manaf))
            ModelState.AddModelError("manaf", "please enter manafactuer name");
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc))
            ModelState.AddModelError("desc", "Please enter description name ");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(games))
            ModelState.AddModelError("games", "please enter game name");
```

Comment: Can you confirm you want validate server side only ?

Comment: @NicoD I don't mind which ever would work for me preferably server side but If there's a simpler way which would work for what I am trying to do then I don't mind client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function for validating both divs:

```
function IsValid(divid) {
    var $div = $('#' + divid);
    var result = true;
    $.each($div.find("input[type='text']"), function (i, input) {
        if ($(input).val().length == 0 || $.trim($(input).val()) == '') {
            result = false;
            return;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Check validity and hide `contentone` div

```
if (IsValid('contentone')) {
    $('#contentone').hide();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working, I also have other divs such as 'ItemList' etc, could you possibly show this working on jsfiddle

Comment: @user3668266 It is working as per your scenario of two divs with input field type as text, where is the problem, you might want to do alert(result)

Comment: @user3668266 http://jsfiddle.net/nraina/jP99z/1/ check this link it will alert you the result true or false

Comment: @user3668266 please load jquery lib from top-left side first

Comment: Even when there's no text in the fields in contentone div it still hides and when there is text it doesn't hide when button clicked opposite of what i want.

Comment: @user3668266 remove ! sign a typo  . . check my edits

Comment: That seems to work but for clinet side validation is there any way to show validation summary at the top of the page

Comment: @user3668266 yes you can do that by appending the error message in a string and show that it

Comment: Ok thanks, one more question.. In that div I also have a checkbox and when the user ticks 'yes' it brings up another div inside the original with more input fields and for that reason the user will always have to tick yes and enter something in the fields if he is to pass the validation, is there any way in which if the user ticks 'No' for the checkbox then it still validates